# Как сделать такую цветовую схему в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

Есть ли какие-то готовые шаблоны на цвета и как их можно поставить? Пользуюсь VS19, вручную менять слишком затратно по времени. Есть ли сайт с такими шаблонами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а чем именно это отличается от тем которые уже есть в VS2019?

Comment: это похоже просто темная тема

Comment: @Grundy, расцветкой. По дефолту более бледная и неудобная для меня

Comment: Цвет функций, операторов, переменных  и т.д.

Comment: в студии несколько темных тем, ты все проверил?

Comment: Возможно я не корректно выразился, сама тема окружения меня не смущает, меня интересует как поменять цвет классов, переменных, функций, операторов и тд. В VS нашел как сделать это вручную, но интересуют готовые шаблоны, если они есть конечно

Comment: расширение [Color Themes for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio)

Comment: @timur то темы оформления